# vpms service does not start inside Docker container

Tags: docker

I am a newbie to docker. I have an AMI with a running application in it. I have launched the AMI as an instance. It is based on RHEL 6.5. I have launched an other new ubuntu 14.04 instance and installed docker on it. I have stopped the application instance and  detached the root volume and attached it to my new ubuntu 14.04 instance and mounted it to mount volume using   the command           `sudo mount /dev/xvda1 /mnt/`.

Then I have imported the docker image from the mounted root volume using the command `tar -c -C /mnt/ . | docker import - yourimagename:tag`. My image name is `docimage:v1`. Then I ran the container using command `docker run -it -p 443:443 docimage:v1 /bin/bash`. The container is in running state now. But for the application portal to run I have to go into the container and manually start services like `service httpd start`, `service postgresql start` and `service vpms start`. Now the application portal is showing on the browser. To avoid the manual steps i have created a Dockerfile with the existing docimage:v1 image.

```
FROM docimage:v1
ENTRYPOINT service httpd start && service postgresql start && service vpms start && /bin/bash
```

I have built the new image from dockerfile, `docnewimage:v1`. Now if i run the image the container is running and application is showing in the browser. I have pushed the image to dockerhub and pulled in from other linux machines such as ubuntu 16.04 and amazon linux. the container is running but failing in the vpms service to start. But when I am pulling the image to other ubuntu 14.04 the container is running perfect. Can someone help me out with this ?

Comment: Please read our [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to be able to write your question with code *formatted as code*. Splitting down into paragraphs would also do a great deal of good.

Comment: ...btw, to do things The Docker Way, you should have a different container for each service, not putting all services inside a single container. Similarly, using process supervision mechanisms inside containers is generally frowned on, as opposed to letting the container itself directly own the parent process for the individual service that container runs.

Comment: (It would also be very helpful to provide a [mcve] -- the *shortest possible* complete Dockerfile that reproduces your problem; if the problem can be reproduced without `httpd`, that means taking httpd out, likewise, if it can be reproduced without PostgreSQL, that too can be removed).

Comment: Not to slam you - but don't do... any of that. Don't import, create one from scratch - and don't be starting multiple services, actually don't start any services - Docker is meant to wrong a **single process**